# No adapter endpoint error when calling SOAP service

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, spring-ws, jaxb2-maven-plugin

I have received a wsdl from a client for which I need to create a SOAP service.

The Request message is defined as below ->

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       xmlns="http://xmlns.kt/testservice/V4"
       xmlns:servicestype="http://xmlns.kt/testservice2/V4"
       targetNamespace="http://xmlns.kt/testservice/V4"
       elementFormDefault="qualified"
       attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
  <xs:element name="ReceiveDataReqMsg" type="servicestype:ReceiveDataRequestType">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:documentation>Request message</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I am using spring boot ws and maven jaxb plugin to generate the service.
The problem is the plugin generates the RequestMessage class as ReceiveDataRequestType instead of ReceiveDataReqMsg.

For this i use a binding xjb and then the plugin creates the class as ReceiveDataReqMsg

```
  <bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.1">
<bindings schemaLocation="myschema.xsd">
    <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='ReceiveDataReqMsg']">
        <class name="ReceiveDataReqMsg">
        </class>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

But the problem is when i call the service it just gives an error that no adapter found for the endpoint.(I have the endpoint correctly configured).

If i edit and add a @XMLRootelement to the generated class then i get a nullpointerexception.

Can someone please help.

The generated class looks like this

```
public class ReceiveDataReqMsg
extends JAXBElement<ReceiveDataRequestType>
{

protected final static QName NAME = new QName("http://xmlns.kt/testservice/V4", "ReceiveDataReqMsg");

public ReceiveDataReqMsg(ReceiveDataRequestType value) {
    super(NAME, ((Class) ReceiveDataRequestType.class), null, value);
}

public ReceiveReferenceDataReqMsg() {
    super(NAME, ((Class) ReceiveDataRequestType.class), null, null);
}

}
```